# Defining a many-to-many relationship referencing the same table (EF7/core)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, many-to-many, entity-framework-core

The model has **item** entities. 
And there will be items that are dependent on (*using*) other items. Many-to-many relationship. Example:

```
Item A is used by Item B, C, and F.
Item B is used by Item C, F and H.
```

How one would correctly define directional relationships between different items?

The Item:

```
public class Item
    {
    public int Id
        { get; set;}
    public string Name
        {get; set;}
    }
```

My first approach to define the dependencies would be:

```
public class ItemDependency
{
    [Key]
    public int Id
    { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ItemParentId")]
    public Item ItemParent { get; set; }

    public int ItemParentId{ get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ItemDependentId")]
    public Item ItemDependentId { get; set; }

    public int ItemDependentId { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation [EF7 Many-to-many relationship](https://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modeling/relationships.html#many-to-many):

> Many-to-many relationships without an entity class to represent the join table are not yet supported. However, you can represent a many-to-many relationship by including an entity class for the join table and mapping two separate one-to-many relationships.